# Konvajs shape stroke color lingers after change

Tags: konvajs

I'm trying to change the stroke color of a hexagon on mouseover, and then back to the original color on mouseout.

My problem is that, if I redraw only the hexagon after updating the stroke color, the previous color lingers around the edges of the stroke.

```
hexagon.on('mouseover', function(e) {
  e.target.stroke('red');
  e.target.draw();
});

hexagon.on('mouseout', function(e) {
  e.target.stroke('gray');
  e.target.draw();
});
```

Demo at https://codepen.io/jsgarvin/pen/dmRJXj

Here the original color is gray, and it changes to red on mouse over, but on mouse out it changes back to gray with a red dusting around all of the edges.

If I redraw the entire layer though, it seems to do what I expect, but in my particular use case I expect to have several thousand hexagons, among other things, on the layer, and that seems inefficient to redraw the entire layer if I just need to update one hexagon.  Is there a more correct way to do this that I'm overlooking?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to draw the layer.

```
hexagon.on('mouseover', function(e) {
  e.target.stroke('red');
  e.target.draw();
  layer.draw();  // <<<<< THIS LINE IS THE FIX
  });
```

I found this out as I was coding an alternative which I include below in the snippet. It uses a second shape and we show & hide the two so as to provide the mouseover effect. I can imagine that this will not be viable in all cases but it might help someone out so here is a working snippet.

Left hand is your example copied from your Pen with the fix included, the right is the shape switcher, just for fun.

```js
var stage = new Konva.Stage({
  container: 'container',
  width: 400,
  height: 150
});

var layer = new Konva.Layer();
stage.add(layer);

  var c = layer.getCanvas();
  var ctx = c.getContext();

var hexagon = new Konva.RegularPolygon({
  x: 75,
  y: 75,
  radius: 55,
  sides: 6,
  stroke: 'gray',
  strokeWidth: 10
});
hexagon.on('mouseover', function(e) {
  e.target.stroke('red');
  e.target.draw();
  layer.draw();  // <<<<< THIS LINE IS THE FIX
  });
hexagon.on('mouseout', function(e) {
  e.target.stroke('gray');
  e.target.draw();
  layer.draw();  // <<<<< THIS LINE IS THE FIX
});


var hexagon2 = new Konva.RegularPolygon({
  x: 250,
  y: 75,
  radius: 55,
  sides: 6,
  stroke: 'gray',
  strokeWidth: 10
});
hexagon2.on('mouseover', function(e) {
  e.target.visible(false);
  hexagon3.visible(true);
  layer.draw();
});

var hexagon3 = new Konva.RegularPolygon({
  x: 250,
  y: 75,
  radius: 55,
  sides: 6,
  stroke: 'red',
  strokeWidth: 10,
  visible: false
});

hexagon3.on('mouseout', function(e) {
  e.target.visible(false);
  hexagon2.visible(true);
  layer.draw();
});
layer.add(hexagon);
layer.add(hexagon2);
layer.add(hexagon3);
stage.draw();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/konvajs/konva/1.6.5/konva.min.js"></script>

<p>Left image is OP's version, right is shape-switching. Mouse-over the hexagons.</p>

<div id='container'></div>
```

Comment: Yeah, as I said in my question, drawing the entire layer seems to work, but that seems wildly inefficient.  I was hoping that there was a more appropriate best practice.